# How to create a table that can be filtered when a button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a table which has filter function. The data will be retrieved from firestore database. My code seems to loop forever and I want to modify my code to store the filtered results in an object such as array or others then display it in a table. I hope you can help me with my concern. Thank you so much!

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import db from './firebase';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const App = () => {
  // get current date
  var currentDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

  const handleUpcoming = async () => {
    const response = db.collection('accounts').where('schedule', '>', currentDate);;
    const data = await response.get();
    const newAccounts = data.docs.map(item => item.data())
    setAccounts(newAccounts);
  }

  const handlePast = async () => {
    const response = db.collection('accounts').where('schedule', '<', currentDate);;
    const data = await response.get();
    const newAccounts = data.docs.map(item => item.data())
    setAccounts(newAccounts);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <h1>Appointments</h1>
      <div className="button-container">
        <button onClick={handleUpcoming()}>Upcoming</button>
        <button onClick={handlePast()}>Past</button>
        <div className = "scrollbar">
        <table>
          {
            accounts && accounts.map(account=>{
              return(
              <tr>
                <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.name}
                <div className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.email}</div></td>
                <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.schedule}</td>
                <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.service}</td>
                <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.mobileNumber}</td>
              </tr>
              )
            })
        }
        </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have assigned function **invocations** instead of **references** to those functions for the `onClick` values of **both** of your buttons. Instead of: `onClick={functionName()}` it should be: `onClick={functionName}` (no parentheses) This is likely causing an infinite render loop.

Comment: Thanks bro, it doesnt loop but there are no results displayed. Is there a problem with  my usage of .where method?

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to create these two `useState` Hook

```
const[searchForName,setSearchForName] = useState(""); // this is for the search for name input
const[arrayToShow,setArrayToShow] = useState([]); // the array that you will display inside your jsx
const[click,setClick] = useState(false); // we will toggle this value each time the button is clicked
```

search for name input :

```
 <input value={searchForName} onChange={(e) => {setSearchForName(e.target.value)}} />
```

button to search :

```
<button onClick={()=>{setClick(!click)}}>click to search</button>
```

then this is a function that returns an array based on the **given array**, the **proprety that you want to filter with** and **the value of search**.

```
const findWithPropAndValue = (array, prop, value) => {
if (value === "ALL") {return array;}
 else {
 return array.filter((element) => element[prop] === value);
}};
```

so in your `useEffect` each time the value of `click` changes you update the `arrayToShow` and give it to `jsx`

```
useEffect(()=>{
setArrayToShow(findWithPropAndValue (accounts,"name",searchForName))
},[click])
```

finally in your `jsx`

```
 <table>
      {
        accounts && arrayToShow.map(account=>{
          return(
          <tr>
            <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.name}
            <div className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.email}</div></td>
            <td className="appointmentDataOne">{account.schedule}</td>
            <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.service}</td>
            <td className="appointmentDataTwo">{account.mobileNumber}</td>
          </tr>
          )
        })
    }
    </table>
```